# How to shuffle opacity of class which is added in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement, jquery-selectors

I have added class to to my image using jquery in jquery

```
$('.myimage img').addClass('img_opacity').css({"position":"absolute","z-index":"999","opacity":"0"})
```

Now I want to shuffle opacity of `img_opacity` class  from "0" and "1" with jquery variable `myvar`. Values for this jquery variable are `opa1 and opa2`. How can I shuffle opacity using if else in my above jquery script.

Comment: When do you want it to shuffle? On click, on hover, on load etc.

Comment: Actually myvar values are set using wordpress option setting value. its not an mouse hover or click activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure i understand your question, but maybe thats fiting your needs:

```
var opa1 = 0, opa2 = 1;
$('.img_opacity').each(function(){
    var myvar = $(this).is(':hidden')?opa2:opa1;
    $(this).css({opacity:myvar});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shuffle the opacity on click than this might be the answer http://jsfiddle.net/vleran/ErajA/

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">Shuffle!</a>

<div class="myimage">
  <img class="is-visible" src="http://www.osa-opn.org/opn/media/Images/ImageOfTheWeek/12-10-22.jpg?width=1024&height=1024&ext=.jpg" alt="NASSA"/>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a').click( function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
  if($('img').hasClass('is-visible')) {
    $('img').animate({opacity: 0}, 500).addClass('is-hidden').removeClass('is-visible');
  } else {
    $('img').animate({opacity: 1}, 500).addClass('is-visible').removeClass('is-hidden');
  }
});
```